# Can a Telegram bot subscribe to a channel?

Tags: api, telegram

I'd like to know if a bot can subscribe to a channel, I don't seem to be able to do it.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do it.

Comment: do you think it's possible to somehow parse the content of a channel?

Comment: @sathia you can definitely parse web preview of channel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually a bot can can receive all the messages from a channel — it should be just a member of the channel. See [What messages will my bot get?](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get) in the FAQ. But only a channel admin can "subscribe" a bot to the channel in such a way.

Another way is to use some programmable Telegram client application or library (thanks to the open [MTProto protocol](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto)). For example, see [Telethon library](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) (Python3).

Comment: You can set up kinda polling method and ask telegram each 5 minutes to get messages. Limit is ~25 requests/second so

Comment: Also to elaborate on answer: you should use events in mtproto, like new message in chat (chat is same as channel, look for id and access hash ). For example in Node.js you can use alik0211 library, it's easy to get new messages in callback.