# How to forward/read messages from another channel with telebot?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I have a bot that's supposed to forward news from other news channels. How do I make the bot join these channels so it could access all the messages that are being posted? I'm using [pyTelegramBotApi](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). How should I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible duplicate, see: [Can a Telegram bot subscribe to a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48152731/1300170).

Answer (score 0):

Only a channel admin can subscribe a bot to the channel.

A way that doesn't require admin rights in a source channel is to use the MTProto API (a telegram client library, e.g. [Telethon library](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)) instead of the Bot API.

Comment: Can I use them both? For example, can I use Telebot for handling user input and stuff like that and use Telethon for forwarding messages from other channels?